# Functions that create first thread in Unix

Tags: multithreading, unix, kernel, startup

What is the name of the function that calls two functions of the same name but with different parameters to create the first two kernel threads?

Comment: I've not downvoted (yet) but I can see why others did (although it is a bad practice to only downvote without comment). However, you should be more specific: Are you really asking about Unix kernels in general or do you have a specific kernel in mind (Linux, FreeBSD, ...) ? And if you rewrite your question also fix the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the Linux kernel. In that case you are probably referring to [rest_init()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c#L386) which calls `kernel_thread()` two times to create the `kernel_init` and `kthreadd` threads.